# Change Active Taskbar Application

Tags: taskbar, colors, themes, color-theme, windows-8

I currently have the `Buttons on other taskbars` set so `Never combine` So I can have multiple Chrome windows open and will see multiple Chromes on the taskbar. Now the problem is that sometimes I don't really know which one I'm currently looking at.

Is there a way to have the active application take on a different color or some other indication that it's the active window.

To clarify I don't need the title bar of the application to be a different color, just the "button" that shows up on the taskbar

This is for windows 8

Comment: This would require Chrome to do this in order to acomplish what you want

Comment: @Ramhound Chrome was an example I actually need it for multiple instances of PhpStorm. Is this something the application is responsible for?

Comment: It is to a certain point. It would have to detect multiple instances of itself and based on user choice allow the the taskbar icon to be different colors.  Windows will handle offer a taskbar icon, but it will use the same icon, for every instance and doesn't have the capability you seem to want.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 8 alreay does show a very slight glow to the active window. I was hoping there was a setting somewhere to accentuate it

Comment: What color the glow is handled by the theme, any modification from the theme, would be implemented by the author of the program.  As a programmer you can either support or not support that effect.

Comment: @Ramhound So is there a way to modify the theme to make it a stronger glow? Maybe something else of that nature